# FBX import low subdivision why?

Tags: import

Im pretty much a newb to blender. I have exported a character from UE5 as an fbx. Iimported it into another program and it shows the high level of detail. When I import it into blender it shows a low level of detail when on LOD 0 (which is the high level of detail in UE5) As I say, it doesnt do this when I import into another software. Also, because of this, When I export the mesh out of Blender and back into UE5 it shows a reduced level of detail.
Does blender automaticaly reduce the LOD on import??

Comment: Blender doesn't have any notion of LOD. Perhaps the LODs models are imported but hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem. I have to turn off smooth normals. Now it looks the same level of detail as UE5.